# Two columns in Mysql with uniqueness constraint between column1 and column2

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique, constraints

Let us consider a user table:
Username,email1,email2

Now, I want to make sure that no two rows in this table have any common email address. What would be the best way to ensure this ?

E.g.: If table has row: "Bill,bill@email.com,bill@gmail.com", then
trying to insert a row like "Billy,billy@yahoo.com,bill@email.com" should give an error.

Thanks in advance,
 Chandresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, `check` constraints are not a feature of MySQL. Well, they are, but they're ignored.

Use a [`trigger`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html), instead:

```
create trigger MyValidation after insert on user for each row
begin
    if (select count(*) from user where 
        email1 = new.email1
        or email1 = new.email2 
        or email2 = new.email1 
        or email2 = new.email2) > 0 then
        --I know that the delete could use this logic, but you can
        --insert other instructions here.

        delete from user where username = new.username

    end if
end
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question I have posed. But unfortunately my requirements have slightly changed and hence, I will use a separate table for email-user mapping.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to force a combo between 1:1 and 1:multiple with your data model. Your better bet is to store each Username/Email combo separately. One row for "Username,email1" and another row for "Username,email2". If you have additional "Username"-related fields, those could stay in the core User table, while emails would move to a two-column Email table with a multi-column unique index on (Username,Email).

Comment: I just thought of the same answer when planning to look at this page for answers. The reason I choose this is 'username, email,bounced' ... so, you see I need a bounced flag as well and who knows what more later.

Comment: Oh yes, this also prevents the case of a user entering the same email for email1 and email2. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use some sort of stored procedure, but this may be something that you could check for before inserting your data.

```
SELECT email1, email2 FROM yourTable 
WHERE email1 LIKE %@email% or email2 LIKE %@email%
```